# Where can one find a list of prime numbers?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

I am looking for the biggest list of precomputed prime numbers one can find and download. Where should I look?

Comment: Is this some kind of sneaky ad?

Comment: @Did No, I am not affiliated with any of the sites (otherwise I would need to state it as per http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion ). I am looking for a bigger list and just decided to report my current findings in case nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *"External links"* section on the wikipedia page, [List of prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers#External_links) has a [website](http://www.primos.mat.br/indexen.html) that archives all primes up to one trillion, so thats over 37 billion primes.

Answer (score 5):

[Big Primes](http://www.bigprimes.net/faq/) hosts [a torrent link to 1.4 billion prime numbers](http://www.bigprimes.net/pages/archive/1400000000-primes-bigprimes.net.torrent).

[Prime-Numbers](http://www.prime-numbers.org/premium.html) sells a list of prime numbers by their digit size (most lists are a random selection of numbers from a complete list).

NOTE: I am NOT affiliated with any of the sites - I do not run them, I don't know the people that run them, and I do not earn anything for posting those links.

Answer (score 1):

UTM hosts the first [50 million primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/).