# Is there a list of all known Sophie Germain prime numbers?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, big-list

Is there a list of all known [Sophie Germain prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) available anywhere for download? I found [a small list from OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005384) and [the top 20 biggest of such primes](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=2), but I can't find a list that would contain numbers that are not on the extremes of size.

Comment: Sorry maybe this is a strange comment, but for what do you need such a list? I just can't imagine that such a list would be useful for anything.

Comment: http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/mat/primsophie_en.pdf. It is not the list of all the Sophi Germain Primes.

Comment: Have you thought about how long that list would be? The number of primes $p$ less than $N$ such that $2p+1$ is prime is (heuristically) about $N/(\log N)^2$. It's probably easier to generate as many of these primes as you want on the fly as it is to import a table someone else has made.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I want to use those numbers for Pohlig-Hellman cipher. However, I also have to balance that with performance of various machines the algorithm will be deployed on (desktop and mobile). So I need a list of such numbers in order to be able to find the right bit size sweet spot.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would, but a good list of prime numbers is also hard to come by - http://math.stackexchange.com/q/319570/20958 .

Comment: A good list of primes is probably easier to generate on the fly than to import.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, it would be nice to have a list of primes of various byte lengths. How easy it is to generate primes that are 128, 256, 512 bytes long?

Comment: $512$ bytes is, what, about $1200$ digits? If you have the right software and hardware, I don't think it's hard to generate primes of that size. On a mobile phone, I'm not so sure. I see you have found http://primes.utm.edu/ --- there are links there to computational questions.

Answer (score 3):

Using Gerrys heuristic show us that such a list won't be helpfull at all. With *Mathematica* you can calculate the $10^9$ prime number in a time which is so small, that mathematica only gives $0.$

The $10^9$th prime number is $22801763489$, with Gerrys heuristic we will have about 
$4 \cdot 10^7$ Sophie Germain Prime numbers below this prime. Lets assume every of those numbers will need 1 byte in the list, then this list takes $4 \cdot 10^7 $ bytes, which is about 40 mega bytes.  This may not seem to be much but they still wasting your cache, and when your list gets larger it won' t fit in the cache and so will extremly slow your computations (taking the sophie primes numbers below the $10^{12}$ primes would be a list of about $3$ giga bytes).

And the list alone doesn't help you, as your program needs to find it in the list, if you give your list a nice structure (using sublists etc) you may get a complextiy of $\mathcal{O}(\log(L))$ to find a number inside your list where $L$ 
is the number of numbers in your list.

For a lot of problems this will consume much more time than the factorisation itself.

And as you said yourself it is hard to find such a list, this indicates, that it is not so helpful, cause else it would be easier to find.

Comment: Can try writing a python program for the same? Is it helpful?